# Serializing null values in collection throws NullReferenceException in Protobuf V2.0.0668

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

## 1. NullReference Exception on null values inside nullable collection.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<string> Collecton { get; set; }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProtoTest test = new ProtoTest();
    test.Collecton = new List<string>();
    test.Collecton.Add("A");
    test.Collecton.Add(null);
    test.Collecton.Add("B");
    test.Collecton.Add(null);

    //This code works fine on Protobuf 1.0.0.282
    //But throws exception on Protobuf 2.0.0.668
    byte[] buffer = Serialize<ProtoTest>(test);
    ProtoTest converted = Deserialize<ProtoTest>(buffer);

    //In 1.0.0.282 converted.Collection is having 2 items excluded null values.
    //In 2.0.0.668 Serialization fails with NullReference exception.
    Console.Read();

}
```

## 2. Trying to Creates default instance on null values in side reference type collection

```
[ProtoContract]        
public abstract class NullableBase
{
    public NullableBase()
    {
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int? Value { get; set; }            
}

[ProtoContract]
public class NullableChild:NullableBase
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string StrValue { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoTest
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<NullableBase> RefCollecton { get; set; }

}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nullableBaseType=ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(NullableBase), true);
    nullableBaseType.AddSubType(100, typeof(NullableChild));
    ProtoTest test = new ProtoTest();

    test.RefCollecton = new List<NullableBase>();
    test.RefCollecton.Add(new NullableChild() { StrValue = "A" });
    test.RefCollecton.Add(new NullableChild() { StrValue = "B" });
    test.RefCollecton.Add(null);

    byte[] buffer = Serialize<ProtoTest>(test);
    //For null values on reference type Protobuf is trying to create default instance.
    //Here the type is NullBase and its an abstract class. Protobuf wont be able to create it and throwing exception.
    //Why Protobuf creates default instance for null values.
    ProtoTest converted = Deserialize<ProtoTest>(buffer);
    Console.Read();

}
```

We were using Protobuf 1.0.0.282 and it was excluding null values for reference types and nullable collections on serializing. But in V 2.0.0.668, its behaving in differently for nullable types and reference types . For nullable types it throws NullReferenceException on null values while serializing. But for reference types it got serialized and while deserializing its trying to create default instance for null values.

Why they removed this functionality?. Is there any specific reason for that?. 
If there is any good reason, then for reference and nullable type collection it should throw nullreferenece exception right?  We have tried this solution of "SupportNull" https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=217.

Comment: Which version are you using? Googles or Marcs? I see you've opened an issue on [Googles GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/827), yet you reference a post from marcs google code support forum.